# L'hospitals rule for one-sided derivatives

Tags: limits, derivatives

I am trying to work out a limit of the form:$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}{f(x)\over g(x)}$$ where the limit exists, and each function approaches $0$ in the limit and are continuous, but only piecewise smooth such that the derivative of each is discontinuous for $x=1,2,3,...$

I have convinced myself that L'hosptial's rule for one-sided derivatives (i.e. $h\rightarrow0^+$ or $h\rightarrow0^-$ instead of the usual $h\rightarrow0$) is true, however I am having a hard time seeing if it can be applied here. My thought in the affirmative is that although $f$ and $g$ are not differentiable for all $x$, they are at least one-sided differentiable, since the one-sided limits exist for all $x$, allowing use of either the left or right sided variant of L’hospitals rule.

Comment: It should also be noted that the discontinuities for these derivatives are not infinite, but jump discontinuities.